# How do I report on a particular event count as a percentage of total hits?

Tags: google-analytics

I have an event that fires when something in particular goes wrong (event label: NAR). I want to see if instances of that problem are on the rise.
In the table at the bottom, I can see that this is ~7%

[image]

Now in the explorer by default I can only see the *total* count over time.

[image]

But I want to see percentage over time in the line chart. How can I do this? I searched high and low and couldn't even find a similar question. Maybe I'm using the wrong words, I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only existing metrics
From google analytics to Make the graph where you see total events.

I think you're going to have to have to export the data somewhere and carry on analysis.